# How check if exists the field? SAP GUI Scripting

Tags: sap-gui

How check if exists the field?
I tried it:

```
If session.findById("wnd[1]").setFocus Then
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try e.g. the following:

```
on error resume next
session.findById("wnd[1]").setfocus
if err.number = 0 then
   msgbox "The SAP GUI element exists."
else
   msgbox "The SAP GUI element does not exist."
end if
on error goto 0
```

Regards,
ScriptMan

Answer (score 4):

To avoid using error handling you can use:

```
If Not session.findById("wnd[1]", False) Is Nothing Then
    session.findById("wnd[1]").setFocus
End If
```

The key here is the second parameter in FindById which determines if it raises an error or not if the field or any object in SAP exists. If it is set to False there is no error raised and the object is set to Nothing which you can check as in my code.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is how to see if there's a second window: `wnd[1]`

This should work:

```
Sub test()

    If session.Children.Count = 2 then
        'your code goes here

    End If
End Sub
```

It also has the advantage that it doesn't need to use error handling to work,
so another type of error could occur and still be handled.